# How can I count drupal views group row number?

Tags: drupal

I know how count views row number using views-php and $views->row_index.
but if I have groups in my view like..

-Group 1
node1
node2
-Group 2
node3
node4

when I do $views->row_index, the result like
Group1
1. node1
2. node2
Group2
3. node3
4. node4

but I want count each of by group like.
Group1
1. node1
2. node2
Group2
1. node3
2. node4

How can I do this?

Answer (score -1):

In the view interface you should use the following parameters:

- Format: "HTML list"
- Format > Settings > Grouping field: choose the grouping field of your
  nodes
- Format > Settings > List type: ordered list

Your content should display in ordered list reseted for each "grouping field value".

Comment: I mean, want to count using views php or programmatically anything like that. using $view->row_index, cound't count its row in each group.